# Can anyone identify what/where this photo is of?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image]
This is a photo by the Real Photograph Co. (Liverpool) No.684.
I think it may be a crashed WW1 Biplane (lots of the photos with it were WW1 biplanes).

Comment: The engine looks like it's 9-cylinder radial, and given the way the cylinders are seated on the body I suggest the engine is likely to be a Le Rhone 9J. 

There's a fairing behind the pilots head, not large, which has come away revealing possibly access to the tank. That's a big clue. Further, the position of the fairing makes it likely a small single seater.

It's likely WW1 judging from the officer's uniform. Based on that, tentatively it could be an Airco DH5 or Nieuport 17.

Comment: @Party Ark Nice suggestion on the Le Rhone. I would however suggest that it is not  an Airco DH5, I base this on the fact that the DH5 utilized a spinner, which is not in evidence here. The Newport 17 also does not fit, due to the fact that it had a metal seat, while this aircraft has a wicker seat, in addition the Newport did not have a tank behind the seat. I would suggest that this may be a Sopwith Camel, I base this on the fact that the Camel has both a wicker seat and a tank behind the cockpit. I cannot however identify that specific tank design, so this is not an answer just a guess.

Comment: Not all Aircos had spinners (and it might have come off in the crash), but you're right the seat looks wrong. Camel is a good one; I'd expect the tappet rods in front of the cylinders to be visible, but it's not very clear. Certainly the tank position fits, and there is a suggestion of a wing support by the cockpit (left side as you look) which would be a v positive indicator. However, my reading is that there's a fairing behind the pilot's head that's come away - Vickers F.B.19 might be another contender, just to muddy the water. http://www.airwar.ru/image/idop/fww1/fb19/fb19-3.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This could be a Sopwith Camel without its guns.  At least these details don't disagree:

- cowling's shape and front opening
- 9-cylinder radial engine (tappett rods lost when crushed by the cowling)
- 8-bolt prop hub
- wicker seat's weave spacing (many photos if you search "sopwith camel seat")
- fuel tank's position and shape match that in the [Haynes Manual](https://d32ptomnhiuevv.cloudfront.net/en-au/sites/default/files/product_jackets/Haynes-H5795-page-3.jpg)
- location of the remnants of the cabane struts.

Although some of these details are common to many aircraft of the period, it's noteworthy that *this* many details agree in one place.  A statistical argument may be the best one can do with what's been given.

Answer (score -1):

It definitely looks like the nose of a WW1 or pre-WW2 aircraft. You can clearly see the pilot seat with the fuel tank behind it. In addition you can see the engine with  the rest of the two blade propeller.

I personally think that it is most likely a post WW1 but pre WW2 aircraft because it appears to have a NACA Cowling, like on this image from Wikipedia:

[image: NACA Cowling, side, Wikipedia]

[image: NACA Cowling, front, Wikipedia]

It was developed in 1927. As for the aircraft type, for me personally it's hard to tell what it could be.

Source: Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NACA_cowling)